# Crash after sleep when Bluetooth Trackpad and Keyboard are used

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, bluetooth

Since I am using the Bluetooth Keyboard and the Magic Trackpad, my MacBook Pro crashes during the sleep (it doesn't wake up and becomes very hot). Then I need to switch it off using the hardware on/off button.

I found out that the setting that makes the bug appear is the "allow bluetooth devices to wake this computer" from the Bluetooth settings:

[image]

But if I disable that option, after the sleep, the computer takes several seconds before to reconnect to the Bluetooth Keyboard and the Magic Trackpad...

To recap. If I allow bluetooth devices to wake my computer, this makes my computer to crash randomly. If I disallow that option, the computer doesn't find the Bluetooth devices after the wakeup, sometime for several seconds.

Did anybody found a solution for this problem?

I am using a MacBook Pro (Late 2008) with Mountain Lion.

Comment: Did you look in your Console.app (`Application -> Utilities -> Console.app`)for error messages generated around the time your MacBook crashes? This might point to the direction of the crash cause.

Comment: Logs are similar to this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2589283?start=0&tstart=0